# Remove trailing whitespace in df command

Tags: shell-script, disk-usage, string, whitespace

I have the following `df` command:

```
> df -h --output=used,avail,pcent /
 Used Avail Use%
 5.9G   12G  34%
```

Notice how there is a space before `Used` and `5.9GB`

So I did the following:

```
> df -h --output=used,avail,pcent / | awk '{$1=$1;print}'
Used Avail Use%
5.9G 12G 34%
```

It does trim it, but now the `34%` isn't aligned with the `Use%`

How can I fix both of these problems? Strip and keep aligned.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
df -h --output=used,avail,pcent / | sed 's/^ //'
```

Delete the space character at the start of each line.

If left alignment is okay:

```
df -h --output=used,avail,pcent / | column -t
```

**EDIT** (for @guillermo chamorro, see comments):

For a spanish version you can prefix the command with the `LANG` environment variable, e.g.

```
LANG=es_AR.utf8 df -h --output=used,avail,pcent
```

gives me the header names `Usados Disp Uso%` and commas instead of dots.
Your locale must be installed for this, check `locale -a`. On Debian you can add locales with `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: Your sed command leaves a space at the begginig of the second line.

Comment: I am looking at the spanish version which says "Usados" instead of "Used" and the first colum second line does not have a dot: 46G.

Comment: Yes, I thought you wanted to remove one space on each line. You can use `sed 's/^ *//'` to remove all spaces, but then your columns won't be right-aligned any more.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
df -h --output=used,avail,pcent / | awk '{$1=$1;print}' | sed 's/ /\t'/g
```

Replace spaces for tabs.

Comment: Could you explain why you used awk like that?

Comment: @deltaray I just used the code OP posted.